# Changing "wal_level" on PostgreSQL 13 (via client session) is not being respected

Tags: sql, postgresql, wal

On a running PostgreSQL 13 instance, I tried modifying it's `wal_level` system setting as follows, but it's not being respected:

```
postgres@localhost:postgres> SHOW wal_level
+-------------+
| wal_level   |
|-------------|
| replica     |
+-------------+
SHOW
Time: 0.021s

postgres@localhost:postgres> ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = logical;
ALTER SYSTEM
Time: 0.007s

postgres@localhost:postgres> SHOW wal_level
+-------------+
| wal_level   |
|-------------|
| replica     |
+-------------+
SHOW
Time: 0.021s

postgres@localhost:postgres>
```

Unfortunately, this is set in the DockerHub image by the Postgres people, so it's not trivial to just modify a configuration file and restart. Indeed workarounds can be done, but I'm hoping the community can suggest a way to do it live from a Postgres client session.

**EDIT (additional for comment below)**:

```
postgres@localhost:postgres> select * from pg_settings where name ='wal_level';
--+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
  | enumvals                          | boot_val   | reset_val   | sourcefile   | sourceline   | pending_restart   |
--+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------|
  | ['minimal', 'replica', 'logical'] | replica    | replica     | <null>       | <null>       | False             |
--+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Changing wal_level on an already-running server requires a restart.  There is no way around that.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `replica` is the default wal level. That is not specific to the Docker image

Comment: That @jjanes and @a_horse_with_no_name (sounds like a song I know). `=:)` It's too bad they didn't expose that parameter. I'll have to either build the image from scratch, or modify and `commit` a running container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check context field on `select * from pg_settings where name ='wal_level';`
with this value, you can see what "restart" level you need

more info https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html

but, in the doc, for wal_level says:

> wal_level (enum)
>
> wal_level determines how much information is written to the WAL. The
> default value is replica, which writes enough data to support WAL
> archiving and replication, including running read-only queries on a
> standby server. minimal removes all logging except the information
> required to recover from a crash or immediate shutdown. Finally,
> logical adds information necessary to support logical decoding. Each
> level includes the information logged at all lower levels. This
> parameter can only be set at server start.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html

Comment: I added the output of the statement you mentioned to my post. `pending_restart` = `False`. Not sure what that means, but it seems to imply that nothing is waiting for a restart (i.e. perhaps my `ALTER` statement had no effect). But I'm not a `dba` so I'm unsure. Thanks.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer (which has very useful information), but actually the answer is to set the configuration to `logical` prior to starting the database server as @jjanes commented above. I was hoping to avoid this because it means modification of a `Dockerfile` (and maintaining it) or `committing` a running docker image; but it is what it is. `=:)` Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You do not need to change docker image/container if you use Postgresql 14.

Just run

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = logical;
```

and restart the container.

See
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html

> ALTER SYSTEM writes the given parameter setting to the
> postgresql.auto.conf file, which is read in addition to
> postgresql.conf.

Comment: One more step is needed, calling `pg_reload_conf()` function for config reload or db restart

Comment: This also works on Postgres 11.5.

Comment: On Windows, I had to restart the windows service for the change to take effect (after the alter and reload command - v14)

Answer (score 10):

As you will see in the documentation, `wal_level` cannot be changed without restarting the PostgreSQL server. There is no alternative.